# How to combine AND with OR in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I realized that when in node.js I build a query such as:

```
if (hashtagsInput != undefined) {
    var hashtags = hashtagsInput.split(",");
    for(var i=0; i<hashtags.length; i++) {
        query = query.or([{ 'hashtags': hashtags[i] }]);
    }
}

if (friends != undefined) {
    var friendsSplitted = friends.split(",");
    for(var i=0; i<friendsSplitted.length; i++) {
        query = query.or([{ 'facebook_username': friendsSplitted[i] }]);
    }
}
```

then the query is:

```
..., '$or': [ { hashtags: 'test1' }, { hashtags: 'test2' }, {
     facebook_username: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX' }, { facebook_username: 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY' },
     { facebook_username: 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZ' }],...
```

and that will find all records that either have hashtags `test1` or `test2` OR have fb_username `XXXXXX` or `YYYYYYY` or `ZZZZZZZ`.

But how can I write in the `node.js` code the query so that when user puts hashtags then the query fetches entries that have `test1` or `test2` AND fb_username `XXXXXX` or `YYYYYYY` or `ZZZZZZZ`?

If user does not provide any hashtags then it could fetch only fb_accounts and the other way around - if user does not provide fb, then it pays attention only to hashtags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to put AND operator between hashes and username when both are provided, and when one of them is provided you want to search with them only.

```
var query = {};
query.$and = [];

if (hashtagsInput != undefined) {
    var hashtags = hashtagsInput.split(",");
    query.$and.push({"hashtags":{$in: hashtags}});
}

if (friends != undefined) {
    var friendsSplitted = friends.split(",");
    query.$and.push({"facebook_username":{$in: friendsSplitted}});
}
```

You can use $in operator to apply Or condition as you can pass directly array, you don't need to apply for loop.

When user puts hashtags and username both then the query fetches entries that have (test1 or test2) AND (fb_username XXXXXX or YYYYYYY or ZZZZZZZ)

Comment: that worked in a specific case in my app so I will accept it as an answer, thank you! However, after adding more functionality to my app - it resulted in a slightly different problem, I thought about creating a separate question for it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058073/my-mongodb-mongoose-query-conditions-exclude-themselves-can-you-help-me-fixing