# My mongodb/mongoose query conditions exclude themselves. Can you help me fixing that?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

When user submits a content into my `node.js` app, he puts four things: start_date, his facebook username, text content and a flag, whether the content should be visible to everyone or only to his facebook friends.

When user fetches content, he can get the public content from other users and the content from his facebook friends (even when they submitted their content only for their friends).

I created a `mongoose` query that works correctly in this scenario. I do it like this:

```
var query = Test.find({})

if(startDate != undefined) {
    var startDate = new Date(req.param('startDate'));
    query = query.where('updated_at').gte(startDate);
}

if (friends != undefined) {
        var friendsSplitted = friends.split(",");
    for(var i=0; i<friendsSplitted.length; i++) {
        query = query.or([{ 'facebook_username': friendsSplitted[i] }]);
    }
}

query = query.where('hidden').equals(false);

if (publicFlag != undefined && publicFlag === "true") {
    query = query.or({friends_only: false});
}
```

With that code above, when user queries only for content from his friends (that might be private or public), he `POST`s `startDate`, an array of his `friends`, a flag `hidden` set to false and `publicFlag` set to false. A query is constructed:

> Mongoose: test.find({ updated_at: { '$gte': new Date("Sat, 15 Oct 2011
>   00:00:00 GMT")}, hidden: false, '$or': [ { facebook_username:
>   'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' }, { facebook_username: 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY' } ] }) {
>   fields: undefined }

User can also query not only his friends (private or public) content, but also public content of everyone else. For that, he `POST`s `startDate`, an array of his `friends`, a flag `hidden` set to false and `publicFlag` set to true. A query is constructed:

> Mongoose: test.find({ updated_at: { '$gte': new Date("Sat, 15 Oct 2011
>   00:00:00 GMT")}, hidden: false, '$or': [ { facebook_username:
>   'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' }, { facebook_username: 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY' }, {
>   friends_only: false } ] }) { fields: undefined }

Above code works fine.

I want to add another case, when user can fetch content with specific hashtags. 
Basically, when user selects this option, he can see other users' content that only includes those hashtags. That content though is his fb friends posts (private or public) and other people's posts (that is public).

For that I thought about adding this condition to my original `node.js` code:

```
if (hashtagsInput != undefined) {
    var hashtags = hashtagsInput.split(",");

    for(var i=0; i<hashtags.length; i++) {
    query = query.or([{ 'hashtags': hashtags[i] }]);
    }
}
```

but this solution does not work properly.

When user wants to fetch (private and public) content of his friends and public content of others - but only that one that contains one of the hashtags - he `POST`s `startDate`, an array of his `friends`, a flag `hidden` set to false, `publicFlag` set to true and an array of his `hashtags`. When he does it, it creates a query:

> Mongoose: test.find({ updated_at: { '$gte': new Date("Sat, 15 Oct 2011
>   00:00:00 GMT")}, '$or': [ { hashtags: 'test1' }, { hashtags: 'test2'
>   }, { facebook_username: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX' }, { facebook_username:
>   'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY' }, { friends_only: false } ], deleted: false }) {
>   fields: undefined }

Basically I want to limit the general query only to specific hashtags.

This query does not return correct data. Now I'm not a `mongoose` specialist and I've spent couple hours yesterday of trying to figure it out, but I think the problem is that it returns the data that either contains one of the hashtags OR its author is one of my facebook friend.

I would like to fix this query so that - in case user `POST`s hashtags - it fetches the content that is public and private of his friends and public of everyone, but only that one that contains at least one of those hashtags. And when user does not provide the hashtags - it should work as it was, fetching all private and public content of his friends and public of everyone.

Can you please help me fix my `node.js` code so that it creates a correct `mongoose` query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will work as you want

```
var query= {};
query.$and = [];

// and condition on start date
if(startDate != undefined) {
    var startDate = new Date(req.param('startDate'));
    query.$and.push({"updated_at":{$gte: startDate}});
}

// and condition on hastags
if (hashtagsInput != undefined) {
    var hashtags = hashtagsInput.split(",");
    query.$and.push({"hashtags":{$in: hashtags}});
}

// and condition on hidden
query.$and.push({"hidden":false});


// creating a OR condition for facebook friends and public flag
var friend_query = {};
friend_query.$or = [];

if (friends != undefined) {
    var friendsSplitted = friends.split(",");
    friend_query.$or.push({"facebook_username":{$in: friendsSplitted}});
}

if (publicFlag != undefined && publicFlag === "true") {
    friend_query.$or.push({friends_only: false});
}

//Merging facebook friend condition with other condition with AND operator.
query.$and.push(friend_query);


var finalquery = Test.find(query)
```

Sorry I use to create mongodb query directly in Json format, it is little different than you are doing. This will work as you mentioned you want in question.

If it don't solve your problem tell me.

Comment: Thank you Puneet, it works great, I just have a one small additional question - if I want to pass another parameter, such as e.g. username and use it in this query, do I have to modify it by adding: `if (username != undefined) { query.$and.push({"username": username}) }? or is there any other specific way, such as `.equals`, etc?

Comment: You need to use query.$and.push({"username":username}), you can do this with other way also but I am not families with mongoose methods, I also suggest you to directly change mongodb queries, in that way you can make more complex queries.
And please if you found answer useful accept it as correct answer. :)

Comment: Huge Thanks Puneet for your help! one last question - you wrote about changing mongodb queries, what did you mean by that? can you give me some small example here in comments what to change to what? Thanks!

Comment: I mean to say instead of using equal, where, or method of mongoose ODM, you should use mongodb queries, here is the link you can check

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/

Comment: Thank you very much Puneet!